# Failure on installing MySQL on the server

Tags: server, apt, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to install MySQL *(and phpmyadmin)*. Firstly I want to install MySQL using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

But it throws:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've searched a lot for this error with no result `:-(`. I've tried `apt-get -f install` and it throws:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 60463 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Aborting downgrade from (at least) 5.6 to 5.5.
If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.5, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Have you tried manually installing it? `sudo apt install mysql-server-5.5`

Comment: @M.Becerra Email has been sent .. Did you get that?

Comment: @M.Becerra  just one thing, it would be great if you can repair the current mysql ... because I need mysql 5.6 and currently I have some valuable databases on the server ... so please try to repair it first *(instead of uninstall and reinstalling it again)* .. thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

you already have `mysql 5.6` installed on your machine, try this command to see the version

```
mysql --version
```

to start the service try this command:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

if the error persists you could `purge` the existing package and install a new one:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-common 
sudo apt-get purge mysql-client
sudo apt-get autoremove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common 
sudo apt-get autoclean mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
```

To reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client
```

Comment: `mysql: unrecognized service`

Comment: Noted that this ^ is the result of `service mysql start`. And the result of `mysql --version` is `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
`

Comment: try to install `mysql-common` and `mysql-clinet` and then start the service:
`sudo apt install mysql-common`
`sudo apt install mysql-common`

Comment: The same error occurs while installing. Can you please take a look at my server if I give you user and password of my server?

Comment: The fun part is the same error exist while `purging` :-(